# Proving reflexivity and transitivity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, proof-verification

I want to show that if $R$ is reflexive and transitive then $R^{-1}$ is also.

Transitivity:
$$(a,b)\in R^{-1} \wedge (b,c)\in R^{-1} \Rightarrow (b,a)\in R \wedge (c,b)\in R \Rightarrow
 (c,a)\in R \Rightarrow (a,c) \in R^{-1}$$

Reflexivity:
$$(a,a)\in R^{-1} \Rightarrow (a,a) \in R$$

Reflexivity seems little bit odd, is it correct or should I add something?

Comment: Minor correction: the correct spellings are "reflexive" (not "reflective") and "reflexivity".  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof of reflexivity is perfect.

For transitivity, not quite. We assume that $(a,b),(b,c)\in R^{-1},$ but we *don't* want to assume that $(a,c)\in R^{-1}.$ We want to *conclude* that. As a hint for how to do that, since $(a,b),(b,c)\in R^{-1},$ what are some elements that you know must be in $R$?

**Edit**: So long as you justify each step, it looks good.

Comment: I edited my first post, it should be correct now.

Comment: Still not quite there. You need to *justify* that $(c,a)\in R.$ Everything else just follows by definitions.

Comment: $(c,a)$ is in $R$ because $R$ is transitive. I added one implication arrow.